# Why do Pokemon Go gyms "sparkle" sometimes (like right now)?

Tags: pokemon-go

Now is Nov. 16 at 8-pm EST. All gyms are "sparkling". And, in these gyms, none of the icons for the Pokemon that occupy the gym are being shown. What does this mean? Why is it happening?

I'm gonna investigate empirically and go attack one. But, can someone explain this phenomenon?

notes: There is a very bright full moon low in the eastern sky.

here is a photo of what these gyms looked like. When in motion they seem to sparkle to me. As a static photo, not so much sparkle:
[image]

In the next photo, notice that the circles near me, that indicate a pokemon exists, do not have a pokemon at the center.  This seems to prove the pokemon icons were just not being loaded.
[image]

Comment: Could you post a picture to show what you mean?

Comment: @Vemonus yes. I'll send screen shots. But, now even weirder stuff is happening. I'm going to go walk around to investigate. more later.

Comment: were you able to get screenshots? I still think it would be useful to others if there were visuals.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After thinking about your question for a bit, I realized that this has happened to me before as well. This is a bug related to the game loading things.

The giveaway in your question was this:

> And, in these gyms, **none of the icons for the Pokemon that occupy the gym are being shown.**

Whenever Pokémon sprites don't display where they're supposed to, it's definitely a bug. It's certainly not an event, as it has happened multiple times to me (plus there's not really any special holiday right now).

Try force closing and reopening your app, then waiting a few minutes and see if that doesn't make the Pokémon reappear in the gym. That's what always fixes it for me.

Comment: Ah, I'll see a sparkle when checking out a gym for a brief moment, and then the model of the Pokemon does load. This makes complete sense to me and the OP just might have a loading issue.

Comment: @Ellesedil yeah, the word "sparkle" confused me, but I believe they're talking about when it just shows a ray of light beaming down where the Pokémon should be, based on their description. Sometimes it doesn't load after a few minutes. I think this is what confused the OP and made them think it was intended behavior.

Comment: Confirmed its a bug. While walking around, I saw the normal circles that surround pokemon, but I couldn't try to catch them because there was no icon at the center of the circle. The phenomenon ended at exactly 9-pm EST. I didn't get a chance to fight in a gym.